# How do I get my Eclipse C++ project to compile in both Linux and Windows (with Cygwin)?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, windows, cygwin

I'm trying to write some C++ libraries in Eclipse in Linux that can also be compiled in Windows using Eclipse and Cygwin. I've got Cygwin set up on my Windows machine and I can use that to successfully build C++ projects right now that I create in Windows. However, when I create a project in Eclipse on Linux and then import it into Windows, it can't resolve all of my basic include directories. I plan to have four total build configurations: Debug Windows, Debug Linux, Release Windows, Release Linux

Creating the project in Linux:[image]

So then when I import that project into Eclipse on Windows, here's what I see:
[image]
Notice that all of the include directories automatically changed to (almost) the right Cygwin directories. But it can't resolve them because that's not actually the correct path.

If I create a new project from Windows, here's what I see:
[image]
Notice the include directories now start with D:/cygwin64/ so that it can resolve those paths.

Step 1: How can I get the project I imported from the Linux side to successfully find my D:/cygwin64 include directories?

Step 2: How can I get the project I imported from the Linux side to look at an environment variable to see where those cygwin64 directories are so other developers don't have to have the files in the same location?

Comment: Yes, "D:\cygwin64" is in my PATH variable